# JPA 2.0 Criteria API: Select with case and subquery clauses

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

First of all, sorry in advance for the long post but it's a complex issue.

Our product currently has the following working query using the criteria api:

```
SELECT
    pedido0_.rap_num_doc as col_0_0_,
    pedido0_.rap_cod_tip_doc as col_0_1_,
    pedido0_.rap_ver_doc as col_0_2_,
    pedido0_.edo_cod_est_doc as col_1_0_,
    pedido0_.tip_can as col_2_0_,
    pedido0_.num_pro_rea as col_3_0_,
    pedido0_.cod_uti_ges_ped as col_4_0_,
    pedido0_.nom_ges_ped as col_5_0_,
    pedido0_.dte_nifap as col_6_0_,
    pedido0_.nom_tit as col_7_0_,
    pedido0_.cod_uti_cri as col_8_0_,
    pedido0_.uor_cod_uni_org as col_9_0_,
    pedido0_.chv_cod_tip_ped as col_10_0_,
    estadopedi3_.cod_est_ped as col_11_0_,
    procedimen1_.cod_pro_ped as col_12_0_,
    tipodecisa2_.cod_tip_dec_ped as col_13_0_,
    pedido0_.uti_codigo as col_14_0_ 
FROM
    rap_pedido pedido0_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rap_pro_ped procedimen1_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_pro_ped=procedimen1_.cod_pro_ped 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rap_tip_dec_ped tipodecisa2_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_tip_dec_ped=tipodecisa2_.cod_tip_dec_ped 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rap_est_ped estadopedi3_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_est_ped=estadopedi3_.cod_est_ped 
INNER JOIN
    rap_tip_ped tipopedido4_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_tip_ped=tipopedido4_.cod_tip_ped 
WHERE
    pedido0_.dte_nif=?
```

My goal is to make the following changes to the query in the select clause (added the CASE statement):

```
SELECT
    pedido0_.rap_num_doc as col_0_0_,
    pedido0_.rap_cod_tip_doc as col_0_1_,
    pedido0_.rap_ver_doc as col_0_2_,
    pedido0_.edo_cod_est_doc as col_1_0_,
    pedido0_.tip_can as col_2_0_,
    pedido0_.num_pro_rea as col_3_0_,
    pedido0_.cod_uti_ges_ped as col_4_0_,
    pedido0_.nom_ges_ped as col_5_0_,
    pedido0_.dte_nifap as col_6_0_,
    pedido0_.nom_tit as col_7_0_,
    pedido0_.cod_uti_cri as col_8_0_,
    pedido0_.uor_cod_uni_org as col_9_0_,
    pedido0_.chv_cod_tip_ped as col_10_0_,
    estadopedi3_.cod_est_ped as col_11_0_,
    procedimen1_.cod_pro_ped as col_12_0_,
    tipodecisa2_.cod_tip_dec_ped as col_13_0_,
    pedido0_.uti_codigo as col_14_0_ ,
    CASE WHEN (pedido0_.rap_ver_doc = (
            SELECT MAX(a.rap_ver_doc) 
            FROM rap_pedido a 
            WHERE a.rap_num_doc = pedido0_.rap_num_doc AND a.rap_cod_tip_doc = pedido0_.rap_cod_tip_doc AND a.edo_cod_est_doc > 3 AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM rap_pedido b 
                WHERE b.rap_cod_tip_doc = a.rap_cod_tip_doc AND b.rap_num_doc = a.rap_num_doc AND b.rap_ver_doc > a.rap_ver_doc AND b.edo_cod_est_doc > 0
            )
        )
    ) THEN true ELSE false END
FROM 
    rap_pedido pedido0_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rap_pro_ped procedimen1_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_pro_ped=procedimen1_.cod_pro_ped 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rap_tip_dec_ped tipodecisa2_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_tip_dec_ped=tipodecisa2_.cod_tip_dec_ped 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rap_est_ped estadopedi3_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_est_ped=estadopedi3_.cod_est_ped 
INNER JOIN
    rap_tip_ped tipopedido4_ 
        on pedido0_.chv_cod_tip_ped=tipopedido4_.cod_tip_ped 
WHERE
    pedido0_.dte_nif=?
```

To achieve this I've adapted the current select clause using the following code:

```
// Begin new code
Subquery<Integer> subqueryUltimaVersaoDocumentoSubmetidoSemOutroCriado = criarSubqueryUltimaVersaoDocumentoSubmetidoSemOutroCriado(builder,
        query, fromPedido);
Case<Boolean> booleanCase = builder.<Boolean> selectCase();
Predicate versaoIgual = builder.equal(fromPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.versaoDocumento),
        subqueryUltimaVersaoDocumentoSubmetidoSemOutroCriado);
Expression<Boolean> isSubstituicaoPermitida = booleanCase.when(versaoIgual, true).otherwise(false);
// End new code

query.select(builder.construct(Pedido.class, fromPedido.get(Pedido_.id), fromPedido.get(Pedido_.estadoDocumento),
        fromPedido.get(Pedido_.tipoCandidatura), fromPedido.get(Pedido_.numeroProcesso), fromPedido.get(Pedido_.utilizadorGestor),
        fromPedido.get(Pedido_.nomeGestor), fromPedido.get(Pedido_.nifapBeneficiario), fromPedido.get(Pedido_.nomeTitular),
        fromPedido.get(Pedido_.utilizadorCriacao), fromPedido.get(Pedido_.unidadeOrganicaBeneficiario), fromPedido.get(Pedido_.tipoPedido),
        joinEstadoPedido, joinProcedimento, joinTipoDecisao, fromPedido.get(Pedido_.utilizadorProprietario), isSubstituicaoPermitida));
```

Called subquery methods are as follows:

```
private Subquery<Integer> criarSubqueryUltimaVersaoDocumentoSubmetidoSemOutroCriado(final CriteriaBuilder builder,
        final CriteriaQuery<Pedido> query, final Root<Pedido> fromPedido) {
    // Select max(a.rap_ver_doc) From rap_pedido a Where a.rap_num_doc = pedido0_.rap_num_doc and a.rap_cod_tip_doc = pedido0_.rap_cod_tip_doc and
    // a.edo_cod_est_doc > 3 and not exists ...
    final Subquery<Integer> subqueryUltimaVersaoSubmetida = query.subquery(Integer.class);

    final Root<Pedido> fromUltimaVersaoPedido = subqueryUltimaVersaoSubmetida.from(Pedido.class);

    subqueryUltimaVersaoSubmetida.select(builder.max(fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.versaoDocumento)));

    final List<Predicate> where = new ArrayList<>();

    adicionarWhereEquals(builder, where, fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.tipoDocumento),
            fromPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.tipoDocumento));
    adicionarWhereEquals(builder, where, fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.numeroDocumento),
            fromPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.numeroDocumento));

    // Considera todos os pedidos cujo estado seja igual ou maior ao estado passado como argumento
    adicionarWhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(builder, where, fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.estadoDocumento),
            EstadoDocumentoPedido.SUBMETIDO.getId());

    builder.not(builder.exists(criarSubqueryExisteDocumentoCriado(builder, query, fromUltimaVersaoPedido)));

    subqueryUltimaVersaoSubmetida.where(where.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    return subqueryUltimaVersaoSubmetida;
}

private Subquery<Integer> criarSubqueryExisteDocumentoCriado(CriteriaBuilder builder, CriteriaQuery<Pedido> query, Root<Pedido> fromPedido) {
    // select 1 from rap_pedido b where b.rap_cod_tip_doc = a.rap_cod_tip_doc and b.rap_num_doc = a.rap_num_doc and b.rap_ver_doc > a.rap_ver_doc
    // and b.edo_cod_est_doc > 0
    final Subquery<Integer> subqueryUltimaVersao = query.subquery(Integer.class);

    final Root<Pedido> fromUltimaVersaoPedido = subqueryUltimaVersao.from(Pedido.class);

    subqueryUltimaVersao.select(builder.literal(1));

    final List<Predicate> where = new ArrayList<>();

    adicionarWhereEquals(builder, where, fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.tipoDocumento),
            fromPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.tipoDocumento));
    adicionarWhereEquals(builder, where, fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.numeroDocumento),
            fromPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.numeroDocumento));

    adicionarWhereGreaterThan(builder, where, fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.versaoDocumento),
            fromPedido.get(Pedido_.id).get(PedidoPK_.versaoDocumento));

    adicionarWhereGreaterThan(builder, where, fromUltimaVersaoPedido.get(Pedido_.estadoDocumento), 0);

    subqueryUltimaVersao.where(where.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    return subqueryUltimaVersao;
}

protected void adicionarWhereEquals(CriteriaBuilder builder, List<Predicate> where, Expression<?> coluna1, Expression<?> coluna2) {
    where.add(builder.equal(coluna1, coluna2));
}

protected void adicionarWhereEquals(CriteriaBuilder builder, List<Predicate> where, Expression<?> coluna, Object parametro) {
    where.add(builder.equal(coluna, parametro));
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
protected void adicionarWhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(CriteriaBuilder builder, List<Predicate> where, Expression coluna, Comparable parametro) {
    where.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(coluna, parametro));
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
protected void adicionarWhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(CriteriaBuilder builder, List<Predicate> where, Expression coluna1, Expression coluna2) {
    where.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(coluna1, coluna2));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void adicionarWhereGreaterThan(CriteriaBuilder builder, List<Predicate> where, Expression coluna1, Expression coluna2) {
    where.add(builder.greaterThan(coluna1, coluna2));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void adicionarWhereGreaterThan(CriteriaBuilder builder, List<Predicate> where, Expression coluna, Comparable parametro) {
    where.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(coluna, parametro));
}
```

However, I get the following exception when calling the query. Any type of subquery added in the select clause gives me the same result. Is there a workaround to this?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectExpression
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CaseNode.getFirstThenNode(CaseNode.java:43) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CaseNode.getDataType(CaseNode.java:39) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructorArgumentTypes(ConstructorNode.java:166) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:141) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1019) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2279) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2145) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1451) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:571) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1777) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:452) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:221) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:587) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:96) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a lot I think I found an answer.

Apparently, since I'm using JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 4.2.0 as a provider, this isn't possible. Subqueries in select clauses are only supported since JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.0 according to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662336/subquery-in-select-clause-with-jpa-criteria-api)