# Java JPA Criteria Query Subquery in SELECT clause using TupleQuery

Tags: java, jpa, subquery, criteriaquery

I'm trying to configure a subquery in the select clause to achieve an SQL equivalent like this:

> ```
> SELECT 
>   t0.field1 AS a1, 
>   t0.field2 AS a2, 
>   t0.field3 AS a3, 
>   t0.field4 AS a4, 
>   t0.field5 AS a5, 
>   (SELECT COUNT(t1.id) from table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1t1 = t2.field1t2) AS a6
>   
> FROM 
>   table0 t0, 
>   table2 t2
>   
> WHERE 
>   (t2.field1t2 = t0.field5)
> ```

I found some references on how this could be achieved, like this:

[Subquery in select clause with JPA Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662336/subquery-in-select-clause-with-jpa-criteria-api)

So I made my JPA implementation to build a TupleQuery in order to get, first an Entity (all fields - a1..a5 - from table0 in my previous SQL example), and then the count field (a6):

> ```
> CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
>
> // Main Query
> CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
> Root<EntityTable0> root = cq.from(EntityTable0.class);
>
> // Subquery
> Subquery sub = cq.subquery(Long.class);
> Root<EntityTable1> subRoot = sub.from(EntityTable1.class);
> Path<EntityTable2> pathTable2 = root.get("field4");
> Predicate conditionSubquery = cb.equal(subRoot.get("field1t1"), pathTable2.get("field1t2"));
>      
> // Select on the subquery  
> sub.select(cb.count(subRoot)).where(conditionSubquery);
>
> // Multi-select on main TupleQuery
> cq.multiselect(root, sub.getSelection());
> ```

When I run the above JPA code, what I get is this:

> ```
> SELECT
>   t0.field1 AS a1, 
>   t0.field2 AS a2, 
>   t0.field3 AS a3, 
>   t0.field4 AS a4, 
>   t0.field5 AS a5, 
>   COUNT(t1.id)
>
> FROM 
>   table0 t0, 
>   table2 t2, 
>   table1 t1
> ```

So basically, the subquery is not executed, and the "condicionSubquery" predicate is not even taken into consideration.

What Im I doing wrong?  I tested the SQL and it works as expected.

I'm using EclipseLink 2.7 implementation of JPA.

Comment: I got the same error with the same EclipseLink version. Oddly enough, if I write this in JPQL (in your case `select et0, (select count(et1) from EntityTable1 et1 where et1.field1t1 = et0.field1t2) from EntityTable0 et0` _I hope I got your relations right_) it works.